# how to map timestamp attribute in elasticsearch using .net client

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a very simple POCO class as required by elasticsearch .NET client (v8.0 so this is NOT using the NEST client which is deprecated).

for testing I am using a very simple object

```
public class HardwareData
         {            
             public DateTime timestamp { get; set; }
             public int System_ErrorLevel { get; set; }
         }
```

I setup my connection object and then I would like to do someting like:

client.ElasticsearchClientSettings.AttributeMappings.Add("timestamp","@timestamp")

but this is not possible there is a PropertyMappings property but it does not do what I expect (ie map timestamp to the required @timestamp field)

I can achive the result by using an ingest pipeling but there should be a straighforward way to do this.  All examples I have found on internet use the NEST api and not the ElasticsearchClient object that is available in the lateste versions.

if I do not map the timestamp somehow I get an error when I call :

```
 await client.IndexAsync(new IndexRequest<HardwareData>()
              {
                 Document = data
              });
```

where datais of type HardwareData.  the error is that @timestamp is not set.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
public class HardwareData
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "@timestamp")]
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public int System_ErrorLevel { get; set; }
}
```